# Question related to connected set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation, connectedness

I have a problem to understand this proof.
After define D =the component of BUC1.
He claimed that the intersection of D and cl(E)and the intersection of cl(D) and E are both empty.
I'm not sure how this could be empty. I know that E is disconnected....
But I don't know why this is true.

Couod you explain it to me? And could you give me some advice about this kind of proof?
Though this is the first time I learn Elementary topology, it's so unintuitive for me some steps in the proof not only this one. Having a trouble to study through...

THANK YOU for your comment in advance.

Below is the problem and proof.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you include the hypotheses for the sets in the proof ($A$, $B$, etc)?

Comment: @TaisukeYasuda Sorry, I'll add it.

Comment: It ends rather abruptly...?

Comment: Where is the B & E in the proof?  Do you intend D & E.  Where is it needed that the space is metric?  Is this a proposition of general topology?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Right. I mistyped.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I thought that the lest of argument is not important related to my question..